# Walter Lewin Lectures in HD

Tags: soft-question, specific-reference, education

I like the lectures by [Walter Lewin](http://web.mit.edu/physics/people/faculty/lewin_walter.html) 8.0x. However the quality of the videos is pretty bad. Is there any way (DVD, web,...) to get the lecture videos in a good quality, best in HD?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for videos found online and not physics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have both very good news and very bad news for you.

The good news:

The original quality (at least the higher quality I have been able to find) seems to be here:

Go to

http://videolectures.net/mit801f99_physics_classical_mechanics/

then click on one of the lectures, e.g

http://videolectures.net/mit801f99_lewin_lec04/

then look at the right side of the playing video; there are several links:

Download mit801f99_lewin_lec04_01.flv (Video 148.2 MB)

Download Video Download mit801f99_lewin_lec04_01.m4v (Video 113.4 MB)

Download Video Download mit801f99_lewin_lec04_01.rm (Video 113.4 MB)

Download Video Download mit801f99_lewin_lec04_01.wmv (Video 466.0 MB)

Download subtitles Download subtitles: TT/XML, RT, SRT

As you see, the .wmv version weights much more, and it is actually in a much better resolution.

Now, the bad news:

There seems to be no way to massively download all the .wmv files with the lectures. More than that, even if you decide to visit each single lecture page to download them one by one, you have to do it with your navigator, not with kget / wget or any other download manager.

Additionally, the .wmv (windows media video) format is not 100% compatible with my codecs in ubuntu. I cannot play the videos with VLC, but rather have to use other programs, and the aspect ratio has to be manually set every time...

So please, if you find another possibility to download a higher resolution version of these funny lectures, tell it here, or e-mail to ngc6720.at.gmail.com

(Note that there is a couple of isolated higher resolution lectures in youtube, but not the complete collection)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I played it with mplayer without problems. The wmv are not perfect but much better than the youtube versions!

Comment: I asked a question on unix.stackexchange, how to automatically download the videos with a script: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52467/download-from-dynamically-changing-urls-via-script

Answer (score 4):

I have uploaded some of the videos of Walter lewin in HD.

Please find them on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLv_YUveJb90XXmvqieFckx0usRskaM3WS).

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! This answer is a link-only answer, which is frowned upon because links can degrade and render the answer useless. Consider including a summary of the answer provided in the video

Comment: @Jim: While usually correct, this question is essentially asking for links - what should one include more in this post?

Comment: Yeah, I'm with @ACuriousMind here: this is a _very rare_ example of an acceptable (is it?) question for which link-only answers are valid.

Comment: @ACuriousMind My bad. I didn't read the question